# Price Analytics - Price range for a product

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, predictive-models, bounds, marketing

I have data on weekly, total number of units sold, at what price, any discount, at which store, product details.
like below
[image]

For over 3 years for the Product details across 10 stores. 
I would like to find the what is the best price range to get more customers. Is there any study material or methods in this area.

Please let me know how to handle this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the classic ways to approach this problem is to understand a relationship between marginal profit (meaning revenue minus spending) for a given product code (and possibly at a given sales point) conditioned on price. This is also called the price elasticity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_elasticity_of_demand

Usually the first to do is to make sure that you account for:

- seasonality in sales
- different time duration for given price
- other factors (such as marketing interventions, and inflation).

The resulting sales data can then be used to get the marginal profit data, which are plotted as a scaterplot against the variable price. The pattern you will see gives you an idea so as how to proceed next.

The next steps can be building an appropriate model where the price affects the profit.

As an alternative you can just scrutinize the plot and highlight the price region where the margin maximized, which is a (historic) estimate of your optimal price.